# Script not allowed to create schema objects when generating tables despite db_owner role

Tags: sql-server-2012, schema

I am looking to make a "schema only" (no data) copy of a database on my local server. I used **Tasks** -> **Generate scripts** to script the tables from my existing database and then after creating the new database opened a query window and pasted the copied scripts in.

When I ran the scripts I received the following error ...

```
Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The specified schema name "abc" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The specified schema name "xyz" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
```

Now some of the tables I selected to be scripted do make use of different schemas (`abc` & `xyz`) yet I am unsure as to why they cannot be scripted. Looking at my login I am mapped to the `db_owner` role which I would think would give me the appropriate permissions to create the schema. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Does the schema exists on the destination server ?

Comment: Are you sure the script includes the `CREATE SCHEMA` definitions? If not, and the destination database is empty, how is `abc` going to already exist there?

Comment: The schema does not already exists. It is a blank shell of a database. Doesn't the "generate scripts" functionality include the ddl to generate the schemas?

Comment: @webworm did you look at the script you generated? Is it there?

Comment: No it isn't. I just assumed (I know bad idea) that the ddl for generating the schema would be there. How does one generate schema via script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do I understand correctly: you scripted tables **only**, created the database manually and then ran the script to create the tables?

You have to either script the whole database and create the new database using that script (change the DB name if you'll execute it on the same instance) or at least include schemas in the list of database objects to script ("Choose objects" step of the wizard).

> [image]

Comment: Ahaaa! That would be what I forgot. I shall slap myself with a trout several times.